# How can one check if an array contains a substring?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, drop-down-menu, substring

Is it possible to check if an **array** of strings contains a substring? I know how to find whether an array has a complete string match (using $.inArray, arr.includes, arr.indexOf etc...), but these don't match a substring to an array of strings (at least for me).

If I have a `<select multiple>` element with the following options:

```
positive (selected)
positron (selected)
negative
negatron
```

How do can I boolean whether my multiple options array includes the substring `pos`, to indicate that both `positve` and `positron` were in the selections?

I'd like to be able to present my user with some additional questions to answer based on whether certain selections are made, but I don't want to write a bunch of if/then statements to cover the various strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Array.prototype` has very useful `.filter` function for your purpose.

```js
const arr = ['positive', 'positron', 'negative', 'negatron'];

function findMatches() {
  let searchVal = document.getElementById('test').value;
  let res = arr.filter(el => el.indexOf(searchVal) > -1);
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = res.join(', ');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test" />
<button type="button" onclick="findMatches()">Find</button>
<br /> Array: ['positive', 'positron', 'negative', 'negatron']<br />
<span id="result"></span>
```

And then apply your extended logic to the filtered array.

Comment: One more question, if you don't mind. How can I incorporate array.filter into an `if` condition? Meaning, {if (arr.filter(??indexOf('substr')) > -1) { //do logic}

Comment: Back to the OP. If you want *any* match then you can use `.reduce` which returns a single value to compare (`[]` is possible). If you want **all** then compare the answer with the result in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf` to check if an array element contain substring

```js
var testData = ['positive', 'negative']

testData.forEach(function(item) {
  if (item.indexOf('pos') !== -1) {
    console.log('Hava data')
  }
})
```

Comment: Okay, but first iterate through array with each, so each array element is tested with `indexOf`. I get it. Is it possible to directly query the array for substring without the `forEach` step?

Comment: @user1837608 If there's only one element, then have a look at `Array.prototype.find()`, otherwise I would go with the version from Alex with `Array.prototype.filter()`